# Checking understanding of concept

Tags: geometry, matrices

I want to check if I have understood a concept correctly.

**Problem: Describe geometrically the action of an orthogonal $3$ x $3$ matrix with determinant -1.**

**My solution:** The orthogonal $3$ x $3$ matrix with determinant $-1$ is an improper rotation, meaning it is a reflection combined with a proper rotation. In another sense, an improper rotation is an indirect isometry, which is an affine transformation with an orthogonal matrix with a determinant $-1$.

**How do I prove the statement for an arbitrary $3$ x $3$ orthogonal matrix with determinant $-1$?**

Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For this version of the question we will need to know more about the tools you know how to use.

Comment: Ok. I am studying Algebra by Artin and we have just covered orthogonal operators and linear operators, and isometries, as well as proper and improper rotations. I have a moderate background in modern algebra and linear algebra.

Comment: Hm. I remember not doing very well with Artin. Does he talk about the special role reflections in the orthogonal group? I am also not really sure how much geometry you are supposed to know when reading Artin; I didn't know any and I just sort of fumbled through this section. I do think I remember that he describes all orthogonal 3x3 matrices as being something like $[[1, 0],[0, R]]$ where $R$ is a 2D rotation, does that sound familiar?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds familiar. We just need to know basic geometry and be able to visualize 3-D space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that any orthogonal matrix is similar to

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & * & * \\ 0 & * & *\end{bmatrix}$$

where the stars represent $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix, then notice that $~\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}~$ is an eigenvector. This means that there is some change of basis such that the span of the new first basis element is an invariant subspace.

- In fact, it is more than invariant, it is fixed pointwise. Why?
- What does this mean geometrically?
- How does the transformation act on a vector in the orthogonal complement?
- Finally, use this to show how the transformation acts on an arbitrary vector. (You can do this only using the subspaces, with no need of either basis.)
- Sanity check: Where did the $-1$ come in to play?

Comment: @Anonymous: Hope this helps! Tell me if you get stuck on one of the parts.

Comment: Yeah this helps quite a bit. Thanks!